# qiskit : how to measure multiple pauli strings

Tags: qiskit, measurement, stim

This seems like a basic operation, but I can't see how it's done in qiskit.

The solution here
[Measuring tensor products of Pauli operators](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20688/measuring-tensor-products-of-pauli-operators) doesn't work anymore.

I get an error "qiskit has no attribute 'aqua'".

Stim has MPP command that does the job, but I'm working with qiskit on this circuit.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** The answer below is for measuring a single Pauli string, which turns out not to be what the question wants (after clarification).

You can implement your own function of Pauli measurement.

`QuantumCircuit.measure` is, by definition, a Pauli $Z$ measurement. Putting an $H$ gate before that gives you an $X$ measurement; Putting *(e.g.)* $HS^{-1}$ before that gives you an $Y$ measurement. These can be confirmed by
$$
\begin{aligned}
HZH = X,\quad (HS^{-1})^\dagger Z(HS^{-1}) = SXS^{-1} = Y. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Besides, measurements of Pauli strings are just tensor products of single-qubit Pauli measurements, so you just need to do the above qubit-by-qubit.

Below is a piece of code I use to generate circuit for Pauli measurement at a certain index (just remember to add `QuantumCircuit.measure` at the end of the circuit).

```
def measure_pauli_1q(circuit,index,pauli=None):
    if pauli == 'I' or pauli == 'Z':
        circuit.id([index])
    elif pauli == 'X':
        circuit.h([index])
    elif pauli == 'Y':
        circuit.s([index])
        circuit.s([index])
        circuit.s([index])
        circuit.h([index])
    else:
        assert 1==0
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I need to measure multiple stabilizers (for example $X_1 Z_2 X_3 X_4$ and $Z_1 X_3 Z_4$...) qubit 1 would be involved as $X_1$ in first and $Z_1$ in second. Measuring a "qubit" is not well defined...you measure operators not qubits.

Comment: So the task is to measure **multiple** Pauli strings that are not bit-wise commuting. In that case, yes, one cannot measure “qubit-by-qubit” as measuring $Z_1$ destroy the information of $X_1$. My understanding is that one needs to rotates to the common eigenbasis of all Pauli strings before measuring, or introduces ancillas. (PS. I would suggest editing the question to make this point clear. The `pauli_measurement` method mentioned [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20688/measuring-tensor-products-of-pauli-operators) also measure qubit-by-qubit, as far as I can tell)

Comment: Edited title to be more explicit. Note that stim handles this directly with MPP command.